# Resume On Error for Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following foreach loop in a powershell script:

```
foreach ($sqlScript in Get-ChildItem -path "$pathToScripts" -Filter *.sql | sort-object) {  
                Write-Host "Running Script " $sqlScript.Name

                #Execute the query
                switch ($removeComments) {
                    $true {
                        (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/', " " -split '\r?\n\s*go\s*\r\n?' -notmatch '^\s*$' |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                    }
                    $false {
                        (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -split '\r?\n\s*go\s*\r\n?' -notmatch '^\s*$' |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The entire script is wrapped with a catch/try block and works OK for errors.

I now have a requirement that if one of the files(scripts) produces an error, the loop will ignore that and move on to the next file.

Could I do this with nested catch try blocks or is there a way to resume the loop on an error?

Comment: Use loop labels.  [Have a look at this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Basically, you'd have `:myloop foreach ...` and when your condition is met, you'd use `continue myloop` which will skip the rest of that iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an additional Try..Catch would probably be the way to go. For example you could modify your `ForEach-Object` blocks as follows:

```
Try {
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); 
    $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
} Catch {
    Write-Error "$($SqlCmd.CommandText) resulted in an error"
    $_
}
```

Note the `$_` within the `Catch` block would contain the error that occurred. After the `Catch` is executed the rest of the script should then carry on as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ErrorAction` preference as `SilentlyContinue` wherever there is an executing statement or a statement which you feel is likely to throw an error. In you current script, you can do this -

```
foreach ($sqlScript in Get-ChildItem -path "$pathToScripts" -Filter *.sql | sort-object)
{  
    Write-Host "Running Script " $sqlScript.Name

    #Execute the query
    switch ($removeComments)
    {
        $true
        {
            (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/', " " -split '\r?\n\s*go\s*\r\n?' -notmatch '^\s*$'  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
        }
        $false
        {
            (Get-Content $sqlScript.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String) -split '\r?\n\s*go\s*\r\n?' -notmatch '^\s*$'  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                            ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/11/02/erroraction-and-errorvariable/) and [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/09/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/) link for details.

Comment: I don't think this would work because I don't think it's `Get-Content` that he's expecting to generate the error.

Comment: @MarkWragg - Hmmm.... Yes in that case, your proposed solution of an additional try..catch block would do.

Comment: @MarkWragg - Actualy Vivek was correct, it is the SQL I want to handle the error on. Could the SilentyContinue option be a variable so I can make it optional?

Comment: Vivek's answer is changing the error behaviour of the `Get-Content` cmdlet only, so it will only stop occurring if you're unable to read the script from the filesystem for some reason, not if it then fails to execute successfully.

Comment: Ah right my mistake. I'll try your nested catch try block solution and see how I get on. Many thanks.